# Publish json file generated from exe to Teamcity artifacts

Tags: json, .net, console-application, teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I am new to teamcity and I am trying to do the following:

- I have an exe file in my project & I have a build step in teamcity to
  run the exe.
- When exe runs, it saves a json file in the same folder    as the exe.

How can I publish this json to the artifacts in teamcity?

Answer (score 0):

In your build configuration settings, on the General page, you are able to specify which file(s) or folder(s) to publish as artifacts. You can export the file(s)/folder(s) as is, or zip them. Refer to the documentation and the quick help dialog (mouse-over the little info-icon next to the text field) for syntax flavors.

Simply writing the name of the json file should be enough though. If your build has run once before already, you can click the folder-structure icon on the right to see an example of the contents from the previous run. In this box, you can simply click the content you want exported. Note: this does require a recent run.